# Combobox binding breaks after button click WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight, mvvm

Combobox binding breaks after button click wpf mvvm.  I have used interaction trigger to bind combobox selection changed to an `ICommand`.

```
 <ComboBox  IsEditable="True" Text="Please Select" IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectionChangedCommand}" />
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                </ComboBox>
 <Button Content="Save"  Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" />
```

Binding works fine till save button's command is fired. Once save command of button is fired, combobox `selectionchange` command breaks

Edit:
Items is a list of string like below

```
           "A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5", "A6", "A7", "A8", 
           "B1", "B2", "B3", "B4", "B5", "B6", "B7", "B8", 
           "C1", "C2", "C3", "C4", "C5", "C6", "C7", "C8", 
           "D1", "D2", "D3", "D4", "D5", "D6", "D7", "D8"
```

Selected item is displayed in a readonly textbox and when the alphabet changes, `SelectionChangedCommand` binding breaks (`SelectedItem` is no longer updated but, on clicking save, its updated).

Note that Combobox's SelectedItem is bound to below property of ViewModel.

```
 private string _SelectedItem;
            public string SelectedItem
            {
                get
                {
                    return _SelectedItem;
                }
                set
                {
                    if (_SelectedItem!= value)
                    {
                        _SelectedItem= value;
                        RaisePropertyChanged(() => SelectedItem);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Is `SelectionChangedCommand` from Telerik?

Comment: @elgonzo nope its an ICommand

Comment: You mean, you programmed your own SelectionChangedCommand, deriving from `ICommand`? Anyway, what code are this command and the SaveCommand executing?

Comment: @elgonzo yes I did. Can't disclose it. It does some calculations using SelectedItem.

Comment: Its hard to give any answer with just the details provided here. Can you explain what you mean by "breaks"? Do you mean the `SelectedItem` no longer gets updated? The `SelectionChangedCommand` no longer executes? The `CanExecute` no longer returns true? It could be any number of things, I don't think we can tell with the limited information provided. And can you share what your `SaveCommand` does to the `SelectedItem`? (doesn't have to be the exact calculation code, but does it change the `SelectedItem` value? do anything else related to the `SelectChangedCommand` or its `CanExecute`?

Comment: @user2951819, well, the only thing i can suggest is to run your application in the debugger. Monitor (with the help of a breakpoint), whether the SelectionChangedCommand CanExecute/Execute methods are called and what they are doing. If they are not called, look in the debugger output window for some information regarding failed bindings or triggers.

Comment: @Rachel SelectedItem no longer gets updated

Comment: @user2951819, if SelectedItem doesn't get updated means that the selection doesn't change, right? Which would also mean that the SelectionChangedCommand doesn't have a reason to fire. During debugging, you will need to keep a very close eye on your bindings (especially on sources of the bindings).

Comment: @user2951819 What does your `SaveCommand` do with the `SelectedItem`? Does it refer to the UI's `ComboBox.SelectedItem` at all, or just the DataContext's `SelectedItem`? And can you include the definition of your `SelectedItem` property in your question?

Comment: @Rachel  UI's ComboBox.SelectedItem is bound to SelectedItem property of ViewModel (datacontext). Its just an ordinary property using RaisePropertyChanged. I have edited the question to show the property.

Comment: @user2951819, set a breakpoint on the setter of that property and debug it!

Comment: @elgonzo Thanks. It helped. Was a bug in the logic of the handler of SelectionChangedCommand

Comment: @user2951819, glad to hear you solved the issue :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering why you want to get both, the notification via "SelectedItem" AND the InvokeCommandAction. In the setter of your SeletedItem you can do what you want and you hold the new selection in your hand.